# describe() returned all null values

Tags: python

I was trying to use `describe()` to get some descriptive statistics, but get `nan` values for what should be numerical.

I tried using `axis=0` or `axis=1`, while `axis=1` resulted in correct numerical values, which however is not what I need; `axis=0` did not give numerical values, expect for the nobs.

```
import scipy.stats as scs
import statsmodels.api as sm

arr = log_returns.to_numpy()  #log_returns is the pd.DataFrame, 1200*9
scs.describe(arr, axis=0)
```

I tried with other dataframe, it worked well, but the log_returns looked well.

This is what I got using the code:

```
DescribeResult(nobs=1263, minmax=(array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]), array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])), mean=array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]), variance=array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]), skewness=array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]), kurtosis=array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]))
```

Actually all the nan values should be floats.

Comment: can you post one kind of input?  3 lines are enough for the dataframe arr.  Thanks

Comment: array([[ 0.00319106, -0.00020801,  0.01943055, ...,  0.01673707,
        -0.00785203,  0.00484115],
       [ 0.0168392 ,  0.01185672,  0.02491374, ..., -0.02243826,
        -0.01460924,  0.00407847],
       [ 0.01888372,  0.03193653,  0.00877704, ..., -0.01465269,
         0.00651202,  0.00078617],
       ...,

Answer (score 0):

```
import scipy.stats as scs
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[ 0.00319106, -0.00020801, 0.01943055, 0.01673707, -0.00785203, 0.00484115], 
          [ 0.0168392 , 0.01185672, 0.02491374, -0.02243826, -0.01460924, 0.00407847], 
          [ 0.01888372, 0.03193653, 0.00877704, -0.01465269, 0.00651202, 0.00078617]])#log_returns.to_numpy()  #log_returns is the pd.DataFrame, 1200*9

scs.describe(arr, axis=0)
```

And gives:

```
DescribeResult(nobs=3, minmax=(array([ 0.00319106, -0.00020801,  0.00877704, -0.02243826, -0.01460924,
        0.00078617]), array([0.01888372, 0.03193653, 0.02491374, 0.01673707, 0.00651202,
       0.00484115])), mean=array([ 0.01297133,  0.01452841,  0.01770711, -0.00678463, -0.00531642,
        0.00323526]), variance=array([7.27852276e-05, 2.63671322e-04, 6.73259558e-05, 4.30106436e-04,
       1.16348907e-04, 4.64396381e-06]), skewness=array([-0.66169565,  0.2940851 , -0.36884708,  0.59665684,  0.40799184,
       -0.60877654]), kurtosis=array([-1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5]))
```

I had to do some `statmodels` updates to make it work, but now it seems to be working correctly.

Try to update `statmodels` to the latest version with pip:

```
pip install statsmodels --upgrade
```

If instead you use conda it is better:

```
conda upgrade statsmodels
```

Comment: I actually investigated the entire dataframe and find the last row with all nan s. I remove that row and everything works fine.